# Using multiple databases in integration test project - no such table exists

Tags: .net, sqlite, integration-testing

My project has multiple databases and 2 db contexts, where one is registered in the DI container like normal:
`services.AddDbContext<CommonDbContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(commonDbContextConnectionString)` and the other is created through a `DbContextFactory` and the connection string is injected based on the route of the API call:

```
    public class DbContextFactory : IDbContextFactory
    {
        protected ILogger Log => Serilog.Log.ForContext(this.GetType());
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public DbContextFactory(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        public MyDbContext CreateMyDbContext(string configKey, string? schemaName)
        {
            return new MyDbContext(new DbContextOptions<MyDbContext>(),
                    GetConnectionString(configKey), schemaName ?? "dbo");
        }
     }
```

In my integration test project I am registering the db contexts in a `WebApplicationFactory` together with a `TestDbContextFactory`:

```
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TProgram> : WebApplicationFactory<TProgram>
    where TProgram : class
{
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.UseEnvironment("IntegrationTests");

        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddSqlite();
            services.AddScoped<IDbContextFactory, TestDbContextFactory>();
        });
    }
}
```

AddSqlite happens like this:

```
    internal static void AddSqlite(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Remove(services
            .SingleOrDefault(d =>
                d.ServiceType == typeof(DbContextOptions<CommonDbContext>))!);
        
        services.Remove(services.SingleOrDefault(
            d => d.ServiceType ==
                 typeof(DbConnection))!);

        services.AddSingleton<DbConnection>(_ =>
        {
            var sqliteConnection = new SqliteConnection("DataSource=:memory:");
            sqliteConnection.Open();

            return sqliteConnection;
        });
            
        services.AddDbContext<CommonDbContext>((container, options) =>
        {
            var connection = container.GetRequiredService<DbConnection>();
            options.UseSqlite(connection);
        });
        
        services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>((container, options) =>
        {
            var connection = container.GetRequiredService<DbConnection>();
            options.UseSqlite(connection);
        })
```

And the `TestDbContextFactory` always returns the registered `MyDbContext`:

```
public class TestDbContextFactory : IDbContextFactory
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public TestDbContextFactory(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }
    
    public MyDbContext CreateMyDbContext(string? configKey, string? schemaName)
    {
        var context = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>();
        return context;
    }
}
```

Now, onto the problem. In my test setup I want to seed both the `CommonDb` and `MyDb`, so 'm fetching the contexts from the service provider and running a seeding method:

```
    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        using var scope = _webApplicationFactory.Services.CreateScope();
        var scopedServices = scope.ServiceProvider;
        var db = scopedServices.GetRequiredService<CommonDbContext>();
        var factory = scopedServices.GetRequiredService<IDbContextFactory>();
        var sdb = factory.CreateMyDbContext("DataSource=:memory:", null);

        db.Database.EnsureCreated();
        sdb.Database.EnsureCreated();
        SeedDataClass.InitializeDbForTests(db);
        SeedDataClass.InitializeDbForTests(sdb);
    }
```

When putting a breakpoint on the final bracket and inspecting the `sdb`, I can see that when I expand one of the tables that I seed it has thrown an exception saying `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 1: 'no such table`. My first thought was that registering two db contexts using only one `DbConnection` does not work, but I'm not sure how to register multiple in memory Sqlite db contexts any other way.